# How to uninstall Soluto without reverting changes?

Tags: windows-7

If I write down every change I made to my system with Soluto, and them I remake them again after uninstalling it, I'll have what I want. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but are you sure the changes are reverted if you uninstall Soluto?

Comment: @Steve It explicitly tells me so when I try to uninstall it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soluto is designed to revert your pc back to its initial state when it is uninstalled. There is no way to circumvent this.
This is how Soluto themselves explain it:

> If you uninstall Soluto, we return the
>   computer to the condition it was
>   before the installation. There are
>   many reasons we need to do that. One
>   of them is recover from bad or
>   unexpected or unwanted result of
>   Soluto software
>
> Hope that answers the question
>
> Ishay CTO & Co-Founder Soluto

Comment: That's a nice way of saying: "we don't want you to to uninstall our software. If you do, you should burn in hell and we'll take care of that by slowing down your machine to what it was."

Answer (score 2):

You can't accomplish the "delay launch" feature of Soluto with stock Windows, so technically you can't accomplish the same thing that Soluto does after uninstalling Soluto without programming/scripting.

However, if all you want to do is stop specific programs from ever running at startup, then the tool you really want is [Sysinternals Autoruns from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).  Make sure to run is with a right-click and "Run as administrator" or it won't be able to do what it needs to do.  I recommend looking at the "Login" tab first for all the programs that start on boot.